# Firebase - Accessing Added-Child from Synchronised array returns -1

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have attempted to access a child from a syncronized array after it has been added like so:

```
var postsRef = new Firebase("https://bragr.firebaseio.com/posts");
var ref = new Firebase("https://bragr.firebaseio.com");
var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
$scope.array.$loaded().then(function() {
    // NEW POST IS ADDED:
    postsRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
         var index = $scope.posts.$indexFor(id);
         var tmpPost = $scope.posts[index];
         console.log(tmpPost); // LOGS -1
    });
});
```

It seems that when a new Post is added, the index returns -1 which means that the item is not yet in the list. I assumed the child_added function was called when the child was added to said list. But it seems I am mistaken.

How can I ensure the Item is accessible from the list after it has been added?
I am using Angular Fire, and I am attempting to update the view when a new Item is added by another user.

Answer (score 0):

To respond to new items being added to `$firebaseArray()`, you need to extend it and override `$$added()` as documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html#section-firebasearray

A few relevant questions:

- [Retrieve date from Firebase, angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649198/retrieve-date-from-firebase-angularjs/34687876#34687876)
- [Joining data between paths based on id using AngularFire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299972/joining-data-between-paths-based-on-id-using-angularfire/30311967#30311967)
- [Joining AngularFire paths on a value/key is not working (merging user profiles into records)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359624/joining-angularfire-paths-on-a-value-key-is-not-working-merging-user-profiles-i/32362201#32362201)